# AngularJS: Avoid calling same REST service twice before response is received

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, asynchronous, q

I have two directives, each consuming the same factory wrapping a $q/$http call.

```
angular.module("demo").directive("itemA", ["restService", function(restService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            restService.get().then(function(response) {
                // whatever
            }, function(response) {
               // whatever
            });
        }
    };
}]);


angular.module("demo").directive("itemB", ["restService", function(restService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            restService.get().then(function(response) {
                // whatever
            }, function(response) {
               // whatever
            });
        }
    };
}]);

angular.module("demo").factory("restService", ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
    return {
       get: function() {
           var dfd = $q.defer();
           $http.get("whatever.json", {
               cache: true
           }).success(function(response) {
              // do some stuff here
              dfd.resolve(response);
           }).error(function(response) {
              // do some stuff here
              dfd.reject(response);
           });
       }
    };
}]);
```

Problem:  When I do this

```
<div item-a></div>
<div item-b></div>
```

I get the same web service fired off twice, because the GET from ItemA is still in progress when the GET for ItemB goes.

Is there a way for whichever fires second to know that there's already a request to this in progress, so that it can wait a minute and grab it for free?

I've thought about making an $http or $q wrapper which flags each URL as pending or not but I'm not sure that's the best way.  What would I do if it was pending?  Just return the existing promise and it'll resolve when the other resolves?

Comment: Maybe you can call the service once in your controller and pass the object into both directives?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is to cache the promise and clean it off after the request is done. Any subsequent request in between can just use the same promise.

```
angular.module("demo").factory("restService", ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
    var _cache;
    return {
       get: function() {
          //If a call is already going on just return the same promise, else make the call and set the promise to _cache
          return _cache || _cache = $http.get("whatever.json", {
               cache: true
           }).then(function(response) {
              // do some stuff here
              return response.data;
           }).catch(function(response) {
              return $q.reject(response.data);
           }).finally(function(){
              _cache = null; //Just remove it here
           });
      }
   };
}]);
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  After a long day I guess I just couldn't think to recycle the promise I was already making.  I modified it a little because we're in strict mode, but it's 90% what you had.

Comment: @oooyaya cool.:) feel free to update my answer if you think it is relevant.

Comment: nah, what you have is alright.  there was one weird thing.  we use the deferred pattern so the .then in the provider eventually invokes a .then in the directive via resolve.  however, using .finally(), the order would be provider's then, provider's finally, directive's then - so, by the time the directive's then() went, _dfd was cleared and it blew up.  so, we just unset _dfd in the provider, but after we resolve.  i imagine there's a better way but this is just for a POC.

Comment: You do not need to use deferred pattern at all in your case. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) And remember the promise chains will be executed in the exact order as they are regsitered.

Comment: I really like this answer too (especially with reading material in the comments), but my linter was crapping out at return _cache || _cache = fn(). Apparently, it's bad practice (maintainably ambiguous) to use assignment in a return statement. Just a nit-pick, but linter no likey (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign.html). Easily fixed with return _cache || (_cache = fn()).

Comment: I fixed the assignment errors like this:
     return _response ? _response : _response = $http({... otherwise nice example